# Can I install cadence on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x86 Machine?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I need a [cadence](http://kxstudio.sourceforge.net/KXStudio:Applications:Cadence)-like application to switch between jack and pulse audio. Can I install cadence on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Not Ubuntu Studio or Dream Studio).

Is it going to work ? I already installed : QJackCTL, Pulsejack module etc.

[image]

Comment: You can find the latest Ubuntu installation instructions for KXStudio programs here:
http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Repositories The gist of it is adding the KXStudio repos, and then you'll need to update apt (`sudo apt update`) to pull the packages (including cadence), following by an install of cadence like any other application (`sudo apt install cadence`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just done precisely that. I have not tested the result exhaustively but yes, so far it seems to work. The only thing I would suggest is, use the KX repositories only for the initial install of Cadence and its dependencies; once installed, disable those repositories. That will ensure that the Ubuntu Studio dependencies don't get shot to pieces by KX versions being out of step.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to install **Cadence** and all kxstudio apps from KXStudio repo on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x86.

For that you need to add these two PPAs:

```
ppa:kxstudio-team/ppa
ppa:kxstudio-team/kxstudio
```

Open synaptic package manager and mark **Cadence, Festige, Jackd(Upgrade), QjackCTL(Upgrade)**.

Don't select any other application and don't upgrade everything, especially ffmpeg.

Do not add any other PPAs as they tend to create problems, especially the "kernels and drivers" PPA.

Just install those upper mentioned apps, they will automatically pull down all other required apps from kxstudio repository :)

After installing everything either disable the PPAs or remove them.

Comment: the PPAs in this answer are outdate!! please have  a look at http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Repositories